# Why cloud firestore rule wont match my path pattern?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I have a simple database and I want to make a simple rule but for some reason it doesn't want to match my collection

[image]

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /userPrivate/{user=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the document to fetch correctly.  In the text box that asks you for the location of the document, don't add `/databases/(default)/documents`.  That is added for you automatically.  You should specify the path to the document using the collection and document id.  For example: `/userPrivate/uid` where "uid" is the document id.  You should probably also turn on authentication in the simulator so that the id is matched.

Also bear in mind that when you use a wildcard match with two stars like `/userPrivate/{user=**}`, then `user` variable will contain the entire path of the document, including any subcollections.  This means that you rule will not work for documents within subcollections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your rules as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /userPrivate/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;
    }

  }
}
```

Your wildcard must point to a **single path document** (which is what you get by doing {`user}`) and not match any document under the `userPrivate` collection (which is what you get by doing {`user=**}`, in other words "the rest of the path").

In case you want to allow the user to read/write all the documents included in the `user` document's sub-collections with the same security level, the following rule will do the trick:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /userPrivate/{user} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;

      match /{userCollec=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;
      }

    }

  }
}
```

I would suggest you watch this official Firebase video on Firestore security rules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&, in particular the part starting at 5 minutes.

Comment: Are you certain that the OP doesn't actually want to protect **all** documents, including all those in subcollections, organized under the userPrivate collection? Your proposal doesn't do that.

Comment: @DougStevenson You are right, I am not 100% sure of the OP requirements, therefore I didn't cover the case of sub-collections... I have adapted my answer to cover this case. Thanks for having pointed that out.

Comment: @ditoslav Hi, did you have the opportunity to try the proposed answer?